# Why are the flowers dropping and leaves turning yellow on my potted Freesia?

Tags: diagnosis, indoors, containers, bulbs

I bought a young (I'm guessing, it's 6"-8" tall) Freesia about a week ago. It was doing well at the time of purchase, but it's been all downhill since. Within a few days, the flowers shriveled then finally dropped. Around that time the leaves began to yellow starting at the tip of the leaf gradually making its way down. Most leaf tips are now a light brown.

As I saw this happening, I varied my care.

It was initially outdoors on my porch that receives only morning sun, then I brought it inside to sit under a north facing window that allows light in all day. Next I tried it on my back patio which receives sun from about noon to 7:00pm, but it's so hot right now in North Texas I was afraid to leave it out for more than a day. I returned the Freesia to the window, figuring it was safest for now.

As for watering, I only water if the top inch or so of soil is dry. While watering, I wait for the surface to puddle slightly and then let it drain.

Yesterday, I added maybe an 1/8 tsp. of fertilizer. 3% Nitrogen, 2% Phosphate, 3% Potash, 2% Calcium.

Any and all help or advice would be greatly appreciated- I really do want to save this little guy.

*Click to enlarge*

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

If your plant is Freesia, these are bulbs - they come up, flower for a short period (2-4 weeks) and then die back down again. You may, or may not, get it flower again next year. Feed while the leaves are present so the bulbs can store energy for next year, using something with higher potash content, maybe half strength tomato food for instance, or just a general purpose balanced fertilizer. When the foliage dies down, put the pot somewhere to rest, water sparingly, just to keep the compost from shrinking completely, but not to have the pot damp or wet. If/when growth begins again next year, move to a brighter spot, increase watering.